# Sharepoint Timer Job : Cental admin or feature activated event?

Tags: 2010, 2013, timer-jobs, custom-timer-job, features

I have a Sharepoint Timer job and have scheduled it on hourly basis in my feature activated event. I deploy the code , feature is activated and timer job is set .

```
Code Snippet :

SPHourlySchedule schedule = new SPHourlySchedule();
schedule.BeginMinute = 0;
schedule.EndMinute = 5;
tempJob.Schedule = schedule;
tempJob.Update();
```

I goto central admin and set the timer job to trigger on daily basis at 1.30PM .  How will the timer job work now , it will fire hourly or daily basis ? If it fires on daily basis , then what is the use of setting the above code in feature activated ?

Comment: It will run daily but the code you provided here sets a daily schedule already. You have another code in the event receiver to set it hourly?

Comment: oops :) i corrected the code . So the featured activated code doesnt come into picture if i change through central admin ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of the code is to set the schedule and if you don't change it in Central Admin it will run hourly. Changing it in Central Admin to daily will overwrite the default hourly schadule that you have set in the event receiver.
This is how it should work. I have not tested it.